# Creating Perlin Noise

Tags: interpolation, perlin-noise

I'm trying to wrap my head around generating two dimensional perlin noise. I've been able to produce it in a single dimension however I don't understand how the interpolation works in two dimensions. This is what my octaves look like:

[image]

I know that I should interpolate the values and that will make the image smoother but I don't understand how to do that. I would like to use linear interpolation so could I get some help on the concept of how to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: I admit that I understood the octave, but the gradient/interpolation stuff seems like greek to me. Not to mention the blackbox permutation thing.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this paper: [SimplexNoise](http://webstaff.itn.liu.se/~stegu/simplexnoise/simplexnoise.pdf)

What you need to add to your algorithm is gradients.